# UML use case: listing vs diagram

Tags: uml, use-case

I'm confused about a book I'm reading.

I always thought use cases where some kind of diagram with actors and bubbles like this one from wikipedia :

[image: use case from wikipedia]

But in [Head First Object-Oriented Analysis and Design - O'Reilly](http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfooad/), what are called "use cases" are just listings with main/happy paths and alternate paths.

O'Reilly provides a sample from this book [here](http://oreilly.com/catalog/hfobjects/chapter/ch03.pdf) (you can scroll to page 71 of the pdf, which is page 123 in the book) and these listings look like:

```
Main Path
1. Fido barks to be let out.
2. The bark recognizer “hears” a bark.
3. The bark recognizer sends a request to the door to open.
4. The dog door opens.
5. Fido goes outside.
6. Fido does his business.
6.1. The door shuts automatically.
6.2. Fido barks to be let back inside.
6.3. The bark recognizer “hears” a bark (again).
6.4. The bark recognizer sends a request to the door to open.
6.5. The dog door opens (again).
7. Fido goes back inside.
8. The door shuts automatically
```

Which is the *official* "use case", the listing or the diagram?

I guess the diagram can be converted to a few listings, but I don't see how the listing can be converted to a use case diagram. Are they even related?

Which one is wrong? Wikipedia, this book or, most probably, me? (and why?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A use case can be represented in two different ways:

1. graphically it is usually drawn as an oval, and contains a short description of what the use case is supposed to deliver. Many use cases together form the use case diagram
2. The details of each use case are described by writing down each path through the use case. 
   These paths can also be called listings or scenario's.

So, you are both right: a use-case can be described as a set of listings/scenario's/paths, or by an oval in a use-case diagram. They are both the same.

So, in your example, try to describe the "serve food" use case by writing down all the steps the waiter needs to perform to actually get the food from the kitchen to the right table, and you will have your list of steps.

Comment: Can the diagram be considered some sort of "unordered" paths ? For the "serve food" use case, I think the steps are from "client order food" to "waiter serves food", but I don't see how we can see that "pay for food" don't come between

Comment: The diagram is just a collection of use cases. Each use case needs steps to be completed. The "serve food" use case is mostly decoupled from the "order food" use case: imagine that the food is served by another waiter than the waiter that took the order for the food. This is possible, so "serve food" should not contain steps for ordering food. If the food has the number of the table on it, each waiter can pick it up and deliver it to the right table

Comment: I think I begin to understand. The listing is the long version of a use case (what is drawn as an oval)

Comment: The listing can also be converted ("realized") using sequence and/or collaboration diagrams that would show more information regarding the steps.

Answer (score 1):

Use cases **ARE NOT some kind of a diagram**. UML use case diagrams are some tools to help to comprehend overall mix of use cases, actors, extension points etc.

UML diagram can not capture the use case, what it is and all the details needed to negotiate if it really describes the problem that needs to be solved (with customer) and the various aspects that need to be weighted in order to implement it's support in the designed system (follow-up design, architecture, coding)

Respected authority in defining what is a use case and how to capture it is software engineer (or computer scientist)

- **[Alistair Cockburn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alistair_Cockburn)**
- especially his book ["Writing Effective Use Cases", now available online](http://alistair.cockburn.us/get/2465) on his site
- along with other use-case related resources at http://alistair.cockburn.us/Use+Cases.

So use cases are not diagrams, use cases are **ARE NOT simple listings**,

**use cases ARE results of the fine art of [capturing software requirements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Requirements_analysis)**

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to download and study UML superstructure from OMG.
You can read find there an exact definition of UseCase without any "independed authors" interpretation or additions !

[UML Superstructure web page](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/)