# Should i mention all properties in use case description?

Tags: uml, use-case

I am writing a use case description; the use case name is (create contract).
In the scenario part, I say that the user should enter all the information required for the contract to be created, then I start listing that information one by one.

Is it correct to list all properties with exhaustiveness in the scenarios description or no?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23811378/uml-use-case-listing-vs-diagram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write all needed information in UseCase scenario including list of all properties if it is part of UseCase realezation. UML does not define scenario, scenario comes from methodologies. Content and structure of scenario  can correspond to your needs.